# Как найти фрагмент текста в строке используя регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста какие функции нужно использовать. Есть переменная с текстом, мне нужно произвести в ней поиск фрагмента текста используя регулярное выражение [A-z]+(,) , и самое главное это получить первое найденное совпадение.

Comment: Так пробовали? http://goo.gl/mXtcq8

Comment: Пробовали.  Мне нужен реальный совет как произвести поиск в строке используя регулярное выражение и потом получить первое найденное совпадение

Comment: Тогда покажите как именно пытались (ваш код) и в чём конкретно возникла проблема. Как это и предписывается и правилами сайта, и правилами хорошего тона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример использования функции preg_match():

```
$subject = "test, test2";
preg_match('/[A-z]+(,)/', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches); //Array ( [0] => test, [1] => , )
```